# NVIDIA drivers not working (no PRIME either)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, lenovo, nvidia-prime

Fairly new Ubuntu user here (dual-boot with Windows, used to use Arch but that was near impossible to maintain for me). I've been having trouble getting my NVIDIA graphics card to work, because there's no PRIME profile for me to have it recognize my games, and I'm not 100% sure how to switch from the Intel card I have to the NVIDIA card. My NVIDIA X Server Settings is mostly empty, except for a 'nvidia-settings configuration' tab and a 'Application Profiles' tab. There's no PRIME tab (I'm not 100% sure what PRIME is or how it's supposed to change anything, but following the Ubuntu wiki's instructions that's supposed to pop up after installation).

This seems like a frequently asked question, but I can't find solid answers because everyone else seems to be encountering black screens on their initial boot-up, and some other solutions I tried didn't help me (although I haven't tried a fresh install).

I can boot-up just fine, when Ubuntu is loading the screen gets a little static-y that is kind of problematic, but for the most part it's okay and I'm not too worried about that at the moment.

Instead, I'm trying to get my NVIDIA drivers working so that I can play Rocket League. Here are my hardware specs:

> Device: Lenovo Y50-70
>   OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
>   Processor: Intel Core i7-4700HQ CPU @ 2.40 GHz x 8
>   Graphics: Intel Haswell Mobile (what System Settings say on Ubuntu, I have an integrated NVIDIA graphics card with the Intel one)
>   Graphics card: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 860M

The current driver I have installed is: nvidia-375

Please let me know if I should update the post with more helpful information, or if I'm being dumb. I can also post screenshots to be show information that I may be missing. I'm sorry, I've been having trouble with Ubuntu lately, but thank you so much for any help.

EDIT:
Here is the output of `lshw -C video` on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/aQajjUuV)

Comment: Is the nvidia driver in use? (lshw -C video will show the driver for both Intel and Nvidia hardware).  Did you clean up any blacklist nvidia-375 lines in all the files in /etc/modprobe.d?  Those blacklists tend tobe leftovers when you install other, later drivers.

Comment: 1. Disable Secure boot if not yet. 2. Open Nvidia X Server Settings and there you can switch cards, reboot needed.

Comment: @ubfan1 I posted the output of `lshw -C video` as an edit, it describes the NVIDIA card as `*-display UNCLAIMED`. And no i didn't touch /etc/modprobe.d, because I haven't had Ubuntu very long (installed it about three weeks ago) I didn't think there would be other driver stuff minus Nouveau drivers. I'll look at that right now though.

Comment: @MichaelBay I'm worried about what disable Secure boot will do, but I should've moved along and tried it anyways. Going to try right now.

Comment: Disabling Secure Boot fixed it! It was as simple as that, I was just too scared to do so at the moment. Thanks!